# Symfony Serializer: setCircularReferenceHandler() is deprecated

Tags: php, symfony, serialization

Symfony's (FrameworkBundle v4.2.5) serializer component (v4.2.5) now tells me in the logs:

```
php.INFO: User Deprecated: The "Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer::setCircularReferenceHandler()" method is deprecated since Symfony 4.2, use the "circular_reference_handler" key of the context instead.
```

But the thing is, I don't call this method explicitly. This call is actually triggered by the SymfonyFrameworkBundle.

I have this in my framework.yaml:

```
serializer:
  enabled: true
  circular_reference_handler: Cbp\Utils\CircularReferenceHandler
```

And I see this in the FrameworkExtension (which is provided by the FrameworkBundle):

```
    if (isset($config['circular_reference_handler']) && $config['circular_reference_handler']) {
        $container->getDefinition('serializer.normalizer.object')->addMethodCall('setCircularReferenceHandler', [new Reference($config['circular_reference_handler'])]);
    }
```

So my question is: how do I fix this deprecation notice?

Comment: Is your service `Cbp\Utils\CircularReferenceHandler` correctly declared, and have you tried clearing the cache, to be sure ?

Comment: @tchap I don't see the relevance to your question to be honest. The thing works fine, that's not the problem. But there's a deprecation notice I want to get rid of, and I don't know how.

Comment: You already use the "circular_reference_handler" key, so the deprecation notice _should not be there_ in the first place, that's why I suggested to clear the cache. As for the service, if it's not correctly declared, it might make the "circular_reference_handler" void, thus using `setCircularReferenceHandler` instead, and consequently, displaying the deprecation notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out to be a bug in the documentation and the FrameworkExtension.

The bug report can be found [here](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/30998).